# Changed PHP Version from 7.0.7 to 7.2.2 and back to 7.0 7 Now PHP is no longer working

Tags: php, windows, apache, configuration

I was testing an application to see if it would work in 7.0.7 and 7.2.2.  The app works in both; that's not where the problem lies.

After seeing the app works in 7.2.2 I changed the Windows Apache httpd.conf file to:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php_7_0_7/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php_7_0_7/"
```

from:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php_7_2_2/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php_7_2_2/"
```

After changing the paths I restarted Apache.

Going to the URL localhost the webpage comes up correctly.

Going to localhost/phpinfo.php does not come up. The error message is "The site cannot be reached."  The file phpinfo.php is simply `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

**The Apache error file has the following:**

[Thu Feb 01 16:03:48.820715 2018] [core:warn] [pid 7628:tid 780] AH00098: pid file C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20151012\nPHP    compiled with module API=20170718\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_fileinfo.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_fileinfo.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_gd2.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_gd2.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_intl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imap.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_imap.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_imap.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ldap: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20151012\nPHP    compiled with module API=20170718\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mbstring.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_mbstring.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_exif.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_exif.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_exif.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_mysqli.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_mysql.dll' (tried: C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n), C:\php_7_0_7\ext\php_php_pdo_mysql.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.\r\n)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20151012\nPHP    compiled with module API=20170718\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xsl: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20151012\nPHP    compiled with module API=20170718\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

When I use the command line and run php -i "print phpinfo();" -> delete.txt is run everything looks OK. The windows environmental variable path includes "C:\php_7_0_7"

**This is the line that I thought would indicate trouble with the extensions:**

```
extension_dir => C:\php_7_0_7\ext => C:\php_7_0_7\ext
```

**That is the correct path to the extensions.**

PHP Error Reporting is set to E_ALL (this is a development machine)

display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On

When a file that is just phpinfo(); the site can not be reached.  Running a file that uses the mysqli extension to connect to a database comes up with this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\www\mysqli.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\www\mysqli.php on line 8"

When phpinfo is run from the command line and saved to a file it includes the lines:

```
mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
```

Which makes me think that php from the command line is working and there is some configuration or communication between Apache and PHP that I'm missing.

The service for IIS is turned OFF.

Edit 1: using the built in server started on the command line with php -S localhost:8000 everything works!  However I would like to use Apache as that is what the main shop runs. Plus the port :8000 at the end of local host breaks the site.

Edit 2: When httpd.exe is stopped as a service and started by double clicking on it, everything runs just like it should.  Perhaps this means there is a permission conflict between the service and the directories.

Update:  works.   does not work.

Is there an error log that is created when PHP starts?

How do I go about troubleshooting this?  I'm on my 2nd hour and I'm seeking advice.

***Thanks for all suggestions.***

Comment: place the extensions in the relative php directory

Comment: All of the extensions are in the relative php directory.  PHP 7.0.7 was working perfectly before installing PHP 7.2.2.  The only thing that was copied to PHP 7.2.2 was the php.ini file which was modified accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar issue after upgrading my php, apache, and mysql stack.  Specifically, everything seemed to work but none of the modules were available and I was sure the extension path was correct. When checking the error log I noticed similar entries to yours with file names like `php_php_{module_name}.dll.dll`.

During this process I copied an old php.ini file which listed module names like so:

`extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll`

but when comparing to the `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` files, all modules are listed like:

`extension=gd2
;extension=gettext`

Just in case there were other changes that I missed, I ended up just copying the proper example file `php.ini-development|php.ini-production` and editing it to fit my environment again but you can probably get away with just removing the `php_` and `.dll` segments from each of the extension listings.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

hi5, encountered the same exact problem today. Seems like lower Apache versions (I had 2.4.18) does properly load curl and openssl extensions. There's also an issue with new php.ini extension format (notice no "php_" and ".dll"), white readme states legacy format is still supported).
What solved my issue with two non-breaking steps:

1. Updated WAMP 3.0.2 to 3.1.1 using [this](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.1.1.exe)
2. Updated Apache to 2.4.29 using [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Apache/)

Don't forget to switch Apache version in WAMP menu after restart and use new extension format in php.ini